# How to use external SD card on Ehndroix?

Tags: external-sd, sd-card

I can't access my SD card via USB. When I plug in to computer it reads only the internal SD. In recovery mode "mount sdcard" doesn't help.

Phone: Samsung S Galaxy GT-19001
Rom: Ehndroix IV

Comment: Does the SD card work normally?

Comment: it depends what you mean by "normally", but I guess that not - at first I thougth that I can access it in android's file explorer (storage/sdcard1) but when I add a test folder there and returned later the folder disappeared

Comment: Normally = at all. Ever. How does your case differ from a situation where the phone or SD card is faulty and never works?  Have you done the obvious and tried your SD card in a different phone, or a different card in your phone?

Answer (score 0):

Since android kitkat, apps cannot access sdcard without special permissions.Most custom roms however bypass this requirement

Comment: OP stated he tried to access it *from PC*, and it did not show up (*access my SD card via USB*). So that's not related. OP also stated to have successfully added a test-folder using a file explorer, and got no error. So I doubt it has to do with Android permissions. So while your statement per-se is correct, it doesn't seem to be related to the issue here.

Comment: I should have wrote not only apps